# execute a remote server php script from a windows batch file on command line

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, execute

I have a php script on my hosted linux/unix server.I want to create a CLI for windows/linux both for executing my PHP script.
for linux i can create a shell script that can execute my php script by using methods like url,curl).
But how can i execute php script from a windows CLI (batch file). If any good suggestion for Linux CLI would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

You can download sh.exe (Bash) for win32 which will let you run the same script on both platforms. On windows then you only need to do `sh.exe script.sh`

I use this method all the time because BAT programming is such a futile and terrible exercise in time-wasting.

http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

EDIT: Oh wait, I thought you were trying to run a PHP script on a website (ie, via wget). I'm not sure what the implications of running PHP as CLI on win32 are.